# How can I enable in 2.8 an overlay of an object's local coordinate system?

Tags: interface

I would like the local coordinate system of an object to be drawn on the object, just like with empties. Is there a way to enable this?

Comment: Can you explain more? What do you mean by local coordinate system? do you mean transform orientation? and what do you mean by " to be drawn on the object"?

Comment: An `Empty` object can be represented by `plain axis` or `arrows`, which show the direction of the empty's local axes. Can something similar be done with a mesh object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different ways to do this.

The first one, go to the Outline view, Object --> Viewport Display, and check `Axis`.

[image]

The end result looks like:

[image]

The second way:

1. Change the `transformation orientation` to local

[image]

2. Enable the `move tool`, on the left hand side of the `3D Viewport` screen

[image]

You should now see the three axes.

[image]

You can also select the other object gizmos (rotation and scaling) from the gizmo drop-down menu.

[image]

From Python you can enable the translate/move gizmo as follows

```
bpy.context.space_data.show_gizmo_object_translate = True
```

Answer (score 1):

How about adding an Empty that shows the arrows that you want, set its parent to the object, and then disable selectability (in the Outliner)?

Comment: That works, but it seems that there should be an easier way -- check a box in the `Overlay` menu that enables drawing these axes.